# Show that $3x^2 + x + 1$ is $\mathcal{\Theta}(3x^2) $by directly finding the constants $C_{1}, C_{2}, k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that $3x^2 + x + 1$ is $\mathcal{\Theta}(3x^2) $by directly finding the constants $C_{1}, C_{2}, k$.

$$C_{1}(3x^2) \le 3x^2 + x + 1\le C_{2}(3x^2)$$

Suppose $k>0$, so $x>0$, then we can easily show that $(3x^2) \le 3x^2 + x + 1$ because $x+1>0$, so $C_{1}=1$.

What about $C_{2}$? I found a solution that goes as follows that I am not sure about,

$$0 \le x^2-x-1\Leftrightarrow3x^2 + x + 1\le 4x^2$$

Then solving for the quadratic equation gives $x=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$. The inequality only holds for $x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$. So, we can conclude that $C_{2}=\frac{4}{3}$?

**Question**: How $C_{2}=\frac{4}{3}$?

Comment: The inequality $3x^2+x+1\leq 4x^2$ is true when $x\geq(1+\sqrt5)/2$. Think about the graph of $4x^2-(3x^2+x+1)=x^2-x-1$.

Comment: @jlammy. Thank you. My question is about $C_{2}$ not the inequality.

Comment: Then $C_2=4/3$ is fine. Recall that for big/little $O$ or $\theta$ notation, only the behaviour of the function in the limit as $x\to a$ matters (here $a=\infty$). So as long as your inequalities hold (in this case) for all sufficiently large $x$, then we are good.

Comment: @jlammy. Thank again, but how we got $C_{2}=4/3 $

Comment: $3x^2+x+1\leq 4x^2=\frac{4}{3}(3x^2)$? ...

Comment: @jlammy. What does it mean for $f(x)$ cannot get closer to $0$ than some fixed, when $x$ is sufficiently large?